# Famous math texts in Spanish

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-spanish

Does anyone know of any well-regarded math text books (e.g., Baby Rudin, etc) that are translated into Spanish?

I'm finding this surprisingly hard to pin down! I'm trying to study for an exam in which we have to translate Spanish math text into English.

Comment: When  I was doing my PhD at an american university there were some courses in which all students were spanish. Spanish was acepted to fulfill the requirement of foreing languges. The fact that english is the _lingua franca_ of science does not mean that there are not scientists, and in particular mathematicians, speaking other languages.

Comment: http://www.icmat.es/press%20outreach/press/Releases/NP-30-01-12
Translation required?

Comment: The *Disquisitiones*, this one is famous! Just google it for a free PDF file in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on amazon.es I have found Spivak's *Calculus* and Lang's *Linear Algebra*:

http://www.amazon.es/dp/8429151362/

http://www.amazon.es/dp/9686630236/

Answer (score 0):

Baby Rudin is translated. Search "Principios de analisis matematico". Also from Rudin: "Analisis real y complejo" y "Analisis funcional". More required?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually tons of them. Three more:

Atiyah-MacDonald's "Introducción al álgebra conmutativa", Massey's "Introducción a la Topología Algebraica" and Lang's "Álgebra" (not the linear one).

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me say that you have some "facsimiles" published by RSME (Euler, etc). The list is available here http://www.rsme.es/content/category/8/28/85/

You can find more books of this kind using a library catalogue: for instance [http://cataleg.ub.edu/search~S1*cat/X?SEARCH=%28%22%3A%20aguilar%22%29&searchscope=1&SORT=D&l=spa&m=a&b=b13](http://cataleg.ub.edu/search~S1%2acat/X?SEARCH=%28%22%3a%20aguilar%22%29&searchscope=1&SORT=D&l=spa&m=a&b=b13) (publisher Aguilar) and [http://cataleg.ub.edu/search~S1*cat/X?SEARCH=%28%22Reverte%22%29&searchscope=1&SORT=D&l=spa&m=a&b=b13](http://cataleg.ub.edu/search~S1%2acat/X?SEARCH=%28%22Reverte%22%29&searchscope=1&SORT=D&l=spa&m=a&b=b13) (publisher Reverte). These lists include books by Lang, Ahlfors, Courant-Robbins, Apostol, etc.

Finally, let me say that I also believe that publishers like UNAM and FCE (Fondo Cultura Economica) have published some other mathematical classics.